# SslMulticastServer creates error NotConnected

Tags: c#

I've tried their example's code, but whatever I do I just get an error and I can't find a solution to the problem.

- SslChatClient
- SslChatServer
- SslMulticastServer
- SslMulticastClient

All of these give the same error, I have tried running the program as admin also tested the lan ip address but the same error keeps popping up.

https://github.com/chronoxor/NetCoreServer/blob/master/performance/SslMulticastClient/Program.cs
https://github.com/chronoxor/NetCoreServer/blob/master/performance/SslMulticastServer/Program.cs

```
Server address: 127.0.0.1
Server port: 3222
Working clients: 100
Message size: 32
Seconds to benchmarking: 10

Clients connecting...Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Client caught an error with code NotConnected
Done!
```

```
Server port: 3222
Messages rate: 1000000
Message size: 32

Server starting...Done!
Press Enter to stop the server or '!' to restart the server...
Chat SSL session with Id 979089a1-435b-4e98-bdd7-515200a26f28 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 398d0f4a-359e-476d-9806-a8e4066a0c73 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 701a07b2-9ca3-4033-a719-122bfae40519 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id fd9fcd43-ea77-4375-a51b-543b36681214 connected!
Chat SSL session with Id 4a4cc2de-c9da-49cb-bb49-82a160c3cc8d connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id db35c8b9-d7b4-4df5-8ac6-43beb3f1d5aa connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 6f65ceeb-77a6-498e-a1f5-26ddcd968643 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 8a0205fc-72bd-4bf3-b529-1fbf743f90bd connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 1b279916-5716-46c3-afbf-6871e3484f40 connected!
Chat SSL session with Id 89709888-2e43-4058-afbe-8e2de2dee250 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 6217f828-ef29-4ed5-afa3-b072fa65faf2 connected!
Chat SSL session with Id eda255c1-1ca5-43e5-9741-8837cd825f28 connected!
Chat SSL session with Id 2f2ae7f2-4fe1-4524-949b-d84d24085205 connected!
Chat SSL session with Id d62650e9-46c3-4438-8636-421a7d5a7369 connected!
Chat SSL session with Id c3b6f171-57ca-4ebf-bcf1-75ed2058d3fa connected!
Chat SSL session with Id 2b70c2a2-0887-43ce-9d1a-0ab36858bb3b connected!
Chat SSL session with Id 09952d90-4b83-4fb1-9a7f-d8adfb11e825 connected!
Chat SSL session with Id 41d8ad80-3803-49ab-91a7-7b4e376c8873 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 4189edab-e829-409c-ab53-f0d79d1de2e7 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 0c191f24-cceb-46af-a3cd-fdae81f5c561 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id c95efc2e-a78c-4cb0-902e-bb48ebc2779b connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id f55ab0ed-0454-476a-a17e-0797b51c5c95 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id f25519c9-fe54-46ba-8ea2-610eb1bc8938 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id f9150582-bc8b-49db-a447-07ac5e45c691 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 69284127-8df1-40a2-bf1d-cd571a8cc32b connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 0934e633-8e42-47e0-b637-ff0fbfcd245c connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 796e5511-a674-472d-b887-fb250c6ce3d5 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 1634f7e6-beb6-474e-9f48-4f3b3f98880e connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id b28ba0b4-f7a2-4ecf-b286-ee424d943ddf connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 564d6d1c-d62b-46a2-b3e0-a545cb640c09 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id b8b0f845-61d0-4860-9a0f-1963f9c0813a connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 471b070e-b5c4-451e-ad71-69cd9408cc56 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id ed6d2c78-91ce-40d8-93e4-17848db9d67e connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 3fccd678-7db1-4e37-aa2e-75dca2ca4523 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 95f7f4da-f23f-49cc-8b01-da4a2b6f953e connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 046e911c-e554-4bfb-9494-88db288e25fc connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 3e428286-9454-4262-92fc-74e22860749d connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 27368ecd-cb66-47e1-bc3f-08d61cd8273d connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 608d5812-8712-4c0d-9d4c-58732e116769 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 90e523a0-37d1-4526-9698-8d1183b0d707 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 0de56918-b1a6-41df-b1b2-34fa2b4bddc1 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id f88e091c-cd77-4a24-87fb-cd680cce8b5b connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 584811ab-34fa-4026-9e8a-0ec1f902cc02 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 707f6c31-c0e0-465e-8107-899de55ec2a4 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id e9c2dc9a-3a14-40f3-bf64-6187daa6f9e4 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 08848aea-af0e-45e0-b68e-304a97e9de41 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 69b04357-17f5-4230-b2a4-93c14d15c82b connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id bd5a8c98-65ad-49d2-9bf2-be4d336e904c connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 59c54f53-d26f-42c4-b02d-e8fb4435b4d6 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id c66baa6b-89d7-4e6f-b528-59fe2451d08c connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 889720c7-050c-41f9-973c-8d950c32e2ab connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id b14f2cbe-19c0-4deb-b563-30a502cb766a connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 1311f090-4e70-4c3d-a3eb-6ce9089b2803 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 95a6ec2a-da96-4761-9d61-1553182ab702 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id f6aa0d28-b07e-4589-b6c9-23a57a25c3d4 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 64c367fd-906d-4a57-8a59-7cdcd8bf9b3a connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 48657214-c0b8-4213-869f-9022cb51834e connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 5a214c44-cbb3-464b-ae6b-db86ee8328b8 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 00014078-4eb4-4d79-95de-8b2813fe991d connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 69771624-8123-4a12-ae24-8c9e32a7758f connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 235cf0ca-4c02-489c-b765-d6372438c22a connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id dfc4cbc5-2399-4c98-86d7-e85a07604477 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id fc443ffa-abbd-4416-9a83-8fa0460ed7b6 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 05a9ab45-6197-4d5f-bd1a-34fb0a3a002f connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id bd5b733d-95f8-43fc-92b5-d11a7d0aeffe connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id e37c390f-ec20-4a72-abb7-dd256b0e4483 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 15b89aa8-7e7a-48fb-95b4-0a54be304665 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 4187bdec-06fc-4f2e-850f-e69e8dfede6e connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 1048ac9e-ff22-4f6f-af30-22351d9d9f33 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 992484c3-c255-489d-adf2-4e13576dd1b5 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id ec5a5fd9-6a1c-4324-93b1-766a5b1df184 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id c6fea5b4-fa20-419b-936e-df66946cdc48 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id a5c9e9f2-314f-47bf-aa97-bef0e89c5438 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 748af377-b55a-4229-9218-84560555ecb7 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 226f3c59-e734-47db-8ade-e171eff99e98 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 84d57442-07ad-4cb8-813d-b8630b5ed79b connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 8a74e1c2-9430-40d8-b644-f329cfceed71 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id cf0a5e3c-28f0-4883-b837-32291635a0e9 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id fbe894a9-fe77-4a64-a8d0-46f765b20c60 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id c80b1c5a-3700-4dbb-9788-7268ef1594b8 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 9b29ce4b-d88a-4a98-ac58-d3db265f8e9d connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id ee4c2e9a-342e-473f-9951-5dc9674b5962 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id d12d1406-6a19-4501-8b7e-5fba3296a421 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 6dacdea9-e831-40e0-8f24-2dee8e0395d2 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id d09b969c-72d2-43d9-a483-7a38564379a8 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 8b4bde06-6885-435d-b239-fb7625f891f9 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 446d7131-c973-416e-9437-f3c2e09b4e08 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 29270632-42ce-4302-a0dd-4dbdbabc54b3 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 828a4983-d654-4fde-9ec3-e04629e1141d connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id fb4e814b-a7f2-4ca9-8d37-2e9e0c397218 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 37bfaeda-88b6-4b2e-8e00-ec84f82a84d4 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id e6e21ec3-d21a-43a5-8346-e992a05120df connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id eccc8f27-6570-4405-b30a-1cb1f32705fb connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 724b23e2-6ff1-432b-b60c-f2481b8ff7dd connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 38f33138-28e8-4393-93a9-d1d59dd65e3e connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id b300517a-78b3-4748-81e3-bbb4148a1fac connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id d4be3cae-86a5-4f9c-8171-247c6057478c connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 2838b360-aab7-4af2-af95-3ade3cd56a13 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id ce0f4fd7-c835-4b53-a9c6-3f8516cb33c0 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
Chat SSL session with Id 0fada91d-2734-485a-90e4-960698cd9e15 connected!
Session caught an error with code NotConnected
```

I expect it to work from the start as it is an example's code and it doesn't say that you should change anything so it should work from the very beginning.

Comment: Is there anything better than NetCoreServer?